# Integrate an Angular SPA in an existing project

Tags: angular, single-page-application, 4d

Currently the project is running with mainly HTML,CSS, and Javascript on the front-end and 4D server as back-end. What I want to do now is integrate an Angular SPA into the project, so basically let the SPA come in and take over the url part. All the tutorials I have been looking at is mainly how to convert a project into using Angular. I have familiarised myself with Angular CLI but I have no idea how to deploy an Angular SPA into an existing project. Do you guys mind pointing me to the right direction?

Comment: Addin your existing project into angular project would be much easier I Guess

Comment: At the moment I only want to experiment with Angular on the project, rather than entirely transferring everything to it.

Comment: so you should try it out on some of the pages from your project

Comment: Yeah, I looked into it and it seems like what I need to do is to bundle the app and deploy all the files in the HTTP server.